# At what point the difference in x-height harm the readability?

Tags: text, typography, guides, readability

For example, when choosing a pair of typefaces to combine in a single line, it is advised that:

- they are from different categories, in order to make them contrast
- they should have the same x-heights, in order to make them smoothly reading

<sub>[(How to know which second typeface should be used, given a contextual typeface?)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/106295/26474)</sub>

I wonder, what if the difference in x-height would be contrast enough, yet the smoothly reading requirement is still satisfied? Therefore, even if the pair come from the same category and it's a no-no, it would become insignificant or even unaffected to the viewer's eyes? How to make such thing happens?

Comment: Graphic design is more of an art than a science. Rules are there to be broken.

Comment: *"Rules? We don't need no stinkin' rules!"* (overheard on a Bolivian trip to a design conference) -- The reality.. guidelines are **guidelines** not end of the world mandatory requirements. Break them whenever a design works better without them.

Comment: To be clear: your example using typography is *only* an example? You're mostly interested in the larger question?

Comment: @ZachSaucier yes. Would it be too broad?

Comment: @Scott does this mean different designers will have different opinions on the same design?

Comment: *"different designers will have different opinions on the same design"* -- EXACTLY. How many designers does it take to screw in a lightbulb? 100 --- 1 to screw it in and 99 to say "I could have done that better."

Comment: @Scott is this better? "How to make the difference in x-height not affect the readability?"

Comment: @Westside Hi, is the edit better?

Comment: The question is really not very clear, but as far as I can understand it still seems very opinion based.

Comment: According to all research in the field, x-height affects readability to some extent. If you want to minimize this or prove the opposite is true, you've found a thesis for advanced research. Good work. You may have also found some field with job security.